# i'm getting "Trying to get property 'notifications' of non-object" error in this code

Tags: php, notifications, onesignal

$response = Notifications(10);

$return = json_decode($response);

foreach ($return->notifications as $notifi)

{
if($notifi->data == null) { ?>

Comment: Can you give us more info about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Hoargarth thanks for your comment. i edit the post for better understandings. please review it again.
i'm getting non-object error on forech.

Comment: You code still seems somewhat off. But anyways, if you get "non-object" error, you are probably trying to access one of your variables like an object, (with `->` operator), even though your variable is not an object. Maybe it's an array. The error message should give you a hint in which line/column it's happening.

Comment: @Hoargarth exactly i'm doing this mistake. i'm trying to access variable in object.. thanks for the corrections

Comment: if (is_array($return) || is_object($return)) {}
i applied this condition on it and error gone.